# Scala - Creating a list from a range of elements in a prexisting list

Tags: scala, list, range, substring, element

As lists are immutable I see that there is no remove index command in scala, like this:

```
// to remove value 3 
val list List() = 3 :: 4 :: 5 :: Nil 
list.remove(list.head)
// to remove value 5
list.remove(list.size)
```

Is it possible to create a list like:

```
// before: list(3,4,5)
val newList = list.listFromRange(2,3) // like substring command
// after: newList(4,5)
```

Would it be feasibile or even possible to create a string for the list and then substring the number? Only issue with this is that if the list contained elements of varying lengths, such as:

```
exampleList: 1,2,10,25,3,4
val newList = exampleList.toString.subString(4, 6) 
// desired value: newList(25,3)
// actual value: newList(0,2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Standard Library has lots going for it. Take some time to study it. It's worth the effort.

```
List(3,4,5).diff(Range(2,4))
//res0: List[Int] = List(4, 5)

List(1,2,10,25,3,4).slice(3,5)
//res1: List[Int] = List(25, 3)
```